# create a button in Word Addin (VSTO) for check the documents

Tags: c#, winforms, vsto, cpu-word, word-addins

I have created a Word Addin for MS Word 2016- 19. with C#. which is working well. I want to create a check button. In the end, this button checks the document for a couple of points, for example, Double spaces, Incorrect cross-references, Double paragraph ("blank line") TBD...
It should generate an overview of the observed issues – for the first step as a list put in a message box. Very important the page number so that the user can check. Even better would be a link directly to the page/paragraph (if possible).
how can I create this report list as a message box?
what is the best way or solution for this purpose?
thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

a messagebox won't do the trick here. Consider a taskpane for this purpose. In there you can have controls to jump directly to the page/paragraph etc.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-add-a-custom-task-pane-to-an-application?view=vs-2019

Comment: how to pass the results to the task pane?